# Can someone explain this loop to me?

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl code. I Know what the end result is: if I run it and pass in an x9.37 file, it will spit out each field of text. That's great, but I am trying to port this to another language, and I can't read Perl at all. If someone could turn this into some form of pseudocode (I don't need working Java - I can write that part) I just need someone to explain what is going on in the Perl below!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Encode;

my $tiff_flag = 0;
my $count = 0;

open(FILE,'<',$ARGV[0]) or die 'Error opening input file';
binmode(FILE) or die 'Error setting binary mode on input file';

while (read (FILE,$_,4)) {
  my $rec_len = unpack("N",$_);
  die "Bad record length: $rec_len" unless ($rec_len > 0);
  read (FILE,$_,$rec_len);
  if (substr($_,0,2) eq "\xF5\xF2") {
    $_ = substr($_,0,117);
  }
  print decode ('cp1047', $_) . "\n";
}
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-w` is the old way of enabling [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings).

[my](http://p3rl.org/my) declares a lexically scoped variable.

[open](http://perldoc.pl/functions/open) with `<` opens a file for reading, the filename is taken from the `@ARGV` array, i.e. the program's parameters. `FILE` is the file handle associated with the file.

[read](http://p3rl.org/read) reads four bytes into the `$_` variable. [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) interprets it as an unsigned 32-bit long (so the following condition can fail only when it's 0).

The next read reads that many bytes to `$_` again. [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) extracts a substring, and if the first two bytes there are "\xf5\xf2", it shortens the string to the first 117 bytes. It then converts the string to the code page 1047.

Comment: Wait, it loops over it in increments of four bytes at a time? I don't think that is doable in java! Uh oh! I may be stuck with perl!

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds Read more closely -- once it's read 4b it then reads more, what moves the file pointer, so it moves over more than 4b in each iteration.  As for "_stuck with Perl_" -- if Java can't do (as you say), you're getting _more_ for your dollars :))  Or, as you now know what the program is doing adapt your Java version as desired.

Comment: I doubt Java can't read 4 bytes from a stream (see e.g. `DataInputStream.readFully`).

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds  The `int read(byte[] b)` from `io.FileInputStream` reads up to `b.length` bytes, for example.

Comment: Also see [`readInt in java.io.DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt()), which also performs the `unpack("N",...)` step.

Comment: Of note, `decode('cp1047', "\xF5\xF2")` produces to `"52"`.

Answer (score 7):

`read (FILE,$_,4)` : read 4 bytes from FILE input stream and load into the variable `$_`

`$rec_len = unpack("N",$_)`:  interpret the first 4 bytes of the variable `$_` as an unsigned 32-bit integer in big-endian order, assign to the variable `$rec_len`

`read (FILE,$_,$rec_len)`: read `$rec_len` bytes from FILE stream into variable `$_`

`substr($_,0,2)`: the first two characters of the variable `$_`

`"\xF5\xF2"`: a two-character string consisting of the bytes 245 and 242

`$_ = substr($_,0,117)`: set `$_` to the first 117 characters of `$_`

`use Encode;print decode ('cp1047', $_)`: interpret the contents of `$_` with "code page 1047", i.e., [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_1047) and output to standard output

Comment: Of note, `decode('cp1047', "\xF5\xF2")` produces to `"52"`.